# How to automatically delete an IOS 4 application?

Tags: ios4, distribution

I am familier with adhoc distribution of an iOS4 app using a link like the one below:

```
href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://example.com/ manifest.plist"
```

Is there a way to delete or update an application using a similar approach?

Mike